# Can my web app use a UNIX socket on OS X Server?

Tags: macos, apache, python, proxy

I'd rather have my Mavericks web app use a UNIX domain socket instead of a TCP port to effect a reverse proxy. I've tried using variants of the Apache syntax for UDS in the `proxies` section of the web app plist but nothing I've tried seems to please OS X Server.

Proxying to gunicorn over TCP port 8001 seems to work in the code below but I'd rather use sockets if I can - keeps my apps separate from OS X Servers' apps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>com.iainhouston.django</string>

        <key>displayName</key>          <!-- Name shown in Server app -->
        <string>TDD Django test at /django</string>

        <key>installationIndicatorFilePath</key>        <!-- The presence of this file indicates web app is installed -->
        <string>/usr/local/python_projects/testwsgi3/hello.py</string>

        <key>requiredModuleNames</key>
        <array>
                <string>proxy_module</string>
        </array>

        <key>proxies</key>
        <dict>
                <key>/django</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>path</key>
                        <string>/django</string>
                        <key>urls</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>http://localhost:8001</string>
                        </array>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[Update: actual code posted above]

If you've tried this I'd be grateful to know how you got on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer is *No* as OS X Server (3.2.1 as of today) comes with Apache 2.2 and from the Apache mod_proxy documents it seems that UDS support wasn't implemented in that release. I was reading a later version's documents.

Not wanting to recompile Apache on our production server, I will have to content myself with TCP ports - no real problem.